# What to use as PurgeCSS extractor for Tailwind 3?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, purge, css-purge

What to use as [PurgeCSS](https://purgecss.com) extractor for Tailwind 3?

With Tailwind 2 we could have used a default extractor that they made available in an internal file, but it was not a public API and in fact it is gone now: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/6162.

What to do with Tailwind 3?

Using extractor copied from Tailwind internals changes code from this:

```css
*,
:after,
:before {
    border: 0 solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
:after,
:before {
    --tw-content: "";
}
```

to this

```css
* {
    border: 0 solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

which is totally wrong (especially for Tailwind 3).

[image]